# I do not want to support javascript turned off in an asp.net mvc web/intranet application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, intranet

I am doing a web application using ajax requests only.

In case there are user trying my application with javascript turned off there should be a nice error message.

When a request comes in to the server there should be automatically an IsAjaxRequest() check and if not show the user a general error.cshtml page.

How can I do that in a generic way for every action and that I have not to manually call this check in every action of my controller?

Comment: Why "only" Javascript? That seems like a lot more work and complication than is necessary, and not a lot to be gained.

Comment: ajax requests + json is good for desktop feeling and speed. Why should I bother not using it? its not more work.

Comment: Sure it is, when you can just use a hyperlink.  No javascript is required.  Additionally, the MVC framework parses forms data, why add the JSON conversion for everything?

Comment: Why not just browse the web in IE5 and disable CSS JS and images...

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs A lot of websites/webapps are built this way nowadays for many reasons. The comments queue is not a place for off-topic discussion :)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine, I think you are misunderstanding.  OP states "web application using ajax requests only"... this disregards all standard POSTS and GETS, controlling all page redirection through Javascript.  It's not a good fit for asp.net-mvc.  I'm not trying to be some HTML purist, but exclusively using Javascript is just as impractical.  I have never seen a website built to not accept HTML standard requests.

Comment: @Jeremy H. for passing the forms data I use form.serialize(); I do not OF COURSE read the textboxes manually with .val() and compose a viewmodel of that data sending to the server. Thats stupid your right;-)

Comment: @Elisa, well that was the thrust of my first comment; I have seen ppl here want to do something exclusively for some religious reason, pretty much shooting themselves in the foot.  Your language suggested you might be one of those ppl and I wanted to challenge the assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<head>
    ...
    <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://example.com/enablejs.php'">
    </noscript>
    ...
</head>
```

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs nowhere is there PHP in the code, it's html :X

Comment: funny, I didn't realize "http://example.com/enablejs.php" was pointing to an HTML page... kinda looks like PHP to me...

Comment: It actually redirects to http://www.iana.org/domains/example/, which in itself is kinda pointless, as it's an empty page.  Should I downvote as not a constructive answer?  :)  I jest of course, but the point is the URL should point to something a little more interpretable.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs have you realized by now that the URL itself is not relevant at all and is just an example ? :P

Comment: I realized it from the beginning, but somebody looking this question up trying to figure out what to do might not.

Comment: I don't think anyone thought the page at the domain example.com was relevant to the question. now you're just trolling.

Comment: @Esailja The answer is not at all what I expected. I did not know this noscript meta etc. I think its good to redirect to another page when the "test web application" is visited by a non-JS user.

Answer (score 2):

```
<noscript>
This web app does not work with JavaScript turned off.
</noscript>
```

Why even let them interact with the app? Just show them a message this way.

Comment: Agreed, but this will not prevent people from making non-javascript based requests.

Comment: people can do a non-ajax request but then I want to show some nice error.